# Can I put an electrolytic motor start capacitor on DC permanently?

Tags: capacitor, motor, electrolytic-capacitor

Can I use an electrolytic non-polar motor start (to be clear: not a motor run but a motor start, not MKP but electrolytic) capacitor across DC permanently without any damage? If no why ? If yes can I use tha VAC label limit as maximum DC voltage?

Comment: How about a link to said capacitor?

Comment: http://www.kemet.com/Lists/ProductCatalog/Attachments/412/KEM_AC104.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer states these capacitors are designed only for intermittent use with a low duty cycle:

> KEMET's MS/MD Series of aluminum electrolytic capacitors are designed
>   for i[n]termittent duty only

and

> The standard rating is 1.67% or 1/60th full time and corresponds to a
>   maximum duty of 20 starts, each of three seconds duration per hour. It
>   is expressed as 3/1.67 (a 3 minute cycle with 1.67% duration during
>   which the capacitor may be energized). If the same capacitor is to be
>   used for a duty cycle of 60 starts per hour the cycle duration will be
>   1 minute. The operation time per cycle will then have to be reduced to
>   1.67% of 1 minute (i.e. 1 second). Alternative duty cycles are available on request.

As such, using them with a constant DC voltage is out of spec, and you're on your own - there's no guarantee they'll function, or for how long.

Comment: That was my question: what should happen if I put across DC, where AC is null (just negligible ripple)?

Comment: @ygg-it Undefined. It's out of spec according to the manufacturer, so anything could happen. You could test it, but there's no guarantee that it will continue working the way your tests came out in future.